# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. Cancel all subscriptions and async using componentWillUnmount and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I am new to react and react native technology and I am stuck into a warning which I am not able to solve.

Two warnings I get:

1. Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it
   indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method in PhoneInput (at Login.js:40)
2. Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it
   indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function in CountryPicker.

Here is my `Login.js`

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
    View, Text,TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet, Image, SafeAreaView,
    TextInput,
    StatusBar, ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { Card } from "react-native-shadow-cards";
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-number-input';
import Styling from "../components/Styling";

const Login = (props) => {

    const phoneInput = useRef(PhoneInput > (null));
    const [phoneNumber,setphoneNumber]=useState(null);
   
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor='#1e3d59' barStyle="light-content" />
            <ScrollView>

 <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/images/login.png')}
                        style={{ height: 150, width: 150, }}></Image>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={[styles.footer]}>
<Text style={Styling.text_footer}>Mobile Number</Text>
    <View style={{marginTop:10,
    alignContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:15,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#d7dade',
        borderRadius:20,
        flexDirection:'row',
        height:72,}}>
                <SafeAreaView >
              <PhoneInput
              containerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                borderColor:'black',
                alignContent:'center',
                height:70,
              }}
              flagButtonStyle={{
                  width:'15%'
              }}
               textContainerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#fff',                
               }}
                            ref={phoneInput}
                            defaultValue={phoneNumber}
                            defaultCode="IN"
                            layout="first"
                            keyboardType='numeric'
                            onChangeText={setphoneNumber}
              ></PhoneInput>
            </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity on onPress={() => props.onSubmit('+91'+phoneNumber)}>
                    <Card style={[containerStyle={
                  height:50,
                  elevation:0,
                  borderRadius:10, 
                  backgroundColor: '#ff6e40',
                  width:"100%",
                  alignItems:'center',
                  alignContent:'center',
                  justifyContent:'center'  
              },{marginTop:30}]}>   
                    <View >
                        <Text style={[Styling.textSign, {color:'#fff'}]}>Request OTP</Text>
                    </View>
                    </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection:"column",
        backgroundColor: '#1e3d59',
        width: '100%',
    },
    header: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        height:"50%",
        justifyContent:"center"
    },
    footer: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom:600
    },
   
});
```

Here is my `App.js`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import VerifyCode from './src/screens/VerifyCode';
import AuthStack from './src/navigation/AuthStack';
import Login from './src/auth/Login';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const App = () => {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  
 const signIn = async (phoneNumber)=> {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      setConfirm(confirmation);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  }

 const confirmVerificationCode= async (code) =>{
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(code);
      setConfirm(null);
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Invalid code');
    }
  }

  auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
      setAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  })
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
{ authenticated? (
        <AuthStack/>
       )
     :
     confirm? (
      <VerifyCode onSubmit={confirmVerificationCode}/>
     )
     : 
     <Login onSubmit={signIn}/>
     }


    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my `VerifyCode.js`

```js
import React, { useState} from "react";
import {
    View, Text,Platform, TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet, Image,
    TextInput,
    StatusBar, ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { Card } from "react-native-shadow-cards";
import Styling from "../components/Styling";

const Login = (props) => {
    const [code, setCode] = useState('');

        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor='#1e3d59' barStyle="light-content" />
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/images/login.png')}
                        style={{ height: 150, width: 150, }}></Image>

                </View>
                <View
                    style={[styles.footer]}>
                      <View style={{marginTop:10,
    alignContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    alignSelf:'center',
    justifyContent:"center",
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#d7dade',
        borderRadius:20,
        height:60,
        width:"40%"
        }}>
<TextInput
placeholder="Enter OTP"
autoFocus
value={code}
onChangeText={setCode}
keyboardType="numeric"
style={{fontSize:20,}}
></TextInput>

        </View>
        <View style={{width:"100%", alignSelf:"center"}}>
            <TouchableOpacity on onPress={() => props.onSubmit(code)}>
                    <Card style={[containerStyle={
                        height:50,
                  elevation:0,
                  borderRadius:10, 
                  backgroundColor: '#ff6e40',
                  alignItems:'center',
                  alignContent:'center',
                  justifyContent:'center'  
              },{marginTop:20}]}>   
                    <View >
                        <Text style={[Styling.textSign, {color:'#fff'}]}>Confirm</Text>
                    </View>
                    </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View></View>
                </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection:"column",
        backgroundColor: '#1e3d59',
        width: '100%',
    },
    header: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent:"center",
        height:"50%"
    },
    footer: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom:600
    },
  });
```

Comment: Does taking out `setAuthenticated`  in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback stop the warning?

Comment: @Keith - even after taking `setAuthenticated` out, problem persist

Comment: You need to share the Code of your PhoneInput and CountryPicker Components since this is where the error comes from. The hole code you in your question is irrelevant.

Comment: @MaximilianDietel - The `PhoneInput` component is in the same Login.js page. The thing is, when i comment the whole `PhoneInput` component in Login.js then its not giving that warning.

Comment: Yes, but I mean the code, you are importing PhoneInput at the top of your LoginPage! But I get that this is from a library so you can't modify the code. The error basically means that the PhoneInput tries to update a state, for example setting phoneNumber to show it in an Input, but you (as example) already navigated to another page so PhoneInput tries to update UI that doesn't show anymore

Comment: @MaximilianDietel - Yes `PhoneInput` is library i imported.  And phoneInput sets the phoneNumber and then i navigate to OTP screen for filling OTP i received in that phoneNumber. That's why i had given all the code here so people can tell what actually i done wrong and what can i do for removing that error.

Comment: Well that confirms my suspection, but since this is a library component I can't really help you sry :( Maybe you will figure out where the error comes from in the future by my description on when it normally appears. Also, its not a really bad error and won't really effect much. You should still fix it tho before "completing" your app :)

Comment: @MaximilianDietel - thanks for help though brother. I appreciate it.